# Camera.getNumberOfCameras() not working on Android 2.2

Tags: android, camera, android-2.2-froyo

I am trying to use API `Camera.getNumberOfCameras()` but getting error "Cannot find symbol" while compiling. My API level is 8.
Can anyone please tell me whats the way to get this function work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[That method](http://goo.gl/ljdAR) was not introduced until API Level 9 (Android 2.3). You cannot use it on older versions of Android. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Camera/Picture) demonstrating how to use it on newer versions of Android while safely avoiding it on older versions of Android.

Answer (score 3):

I know its an old post.But updating for new comers.

From API21 `Camera` class is deprecated.Instead we have to use `Camera2` class.
For gettng connected devices,you have to use something like

```
private CameraManager mManager;
private String[] mCameraIds;
mManager = (CameraManager)getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
mCameraIds = mManager.getCameraIdList();
```

You can find documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager.html#getCameraIdList())

Comment: Do you know if it's possible for there to be more than two cameras in the ID list?